Totals Remaining Tracker for 2 Different Cycle on Excel
Good evening/ Good Morning Everyone,
Maybe I am missing a step or just lack the analytical/ excel creating experience. So, the big picture of what I am trying to accomplish with this Excel spreadsheet is I want to track the remaining funds by subtracting monthly invoice amounts from the total funds QY Term vs OY Term. Then I am hoping 1) Create a formula instead of just taking the total fund ie OY Term 2013 ~ 2014's $379,327.67 - ($24,999.57 July 2013 month invoice amount) = $354,328.10 then keep subtracting from the previous grand total until the end of the term. 2) Is it possible to generate a Pivot Table for tracking remaining funding at a given month or at a given point? 3) If I am about to run out of funding say the remaining funding left in the cycle is less than $5000, I would like to a message in the cell that says "Please request more funding. Thank you!"
Basically, I am trying to create an “up to date” or current snapshot of how much funds I have left for a Project. The challenge is this project lasts for 5 years and the project receives funding annually. But this project starts in November then ends in October (QY Term). Following year, the project renews again in November then ends in October then repeats, however. My organization functions on a July – June funding cycle (OY Term). I would like to know say in April 2013 how much funding I have used from the November – October 2012 -2013 (QY Term) funding bucket vs July – June 2012 -2013 (OY Term) funding bucket.
Is it possible to create a table on Excel that shows me the difference and how much I have used for a specific month ie April 2013 from the QY funding vs March 2014 on the QY or the OY funding cycle? I have attached my work with some numbers. I just couldn’t put it together. Thanks in advance for any guidance or assistance in helping me finishing this spreadsheet. Edit: I have provided a better illustration (I hope in verbalizing and helping everyone to visualize what I am hoping to create in Excel).




A
B
C
D
E







D = Previous maximum amount - Monthly Invoiced amount
E = Previous maximum amount - Monthly Invoiced amount





11/01/2012 ~ 10/31/2013
07/01/2012 ~ 06/30/2013





$                                            295,063.00
$                                            196,708.67




Actual Monthly Invoice Amount
Remaing Funding for QY Term
Remaing Funding for OY Term


1
Nov-12
$                    14,098.73
$                                            280,964.27
$                                            182,609.94


2
Dec-12
$                    12,047.66
$                                            268,916.61
$                                            170,562.28


3
Jan-13
$                    16,040.77
$                                            252,875.84
$                                            154,521.51


4
Feb-13
$                    19,368.87
$                                            233,506.97
$                                            135,152.64


5
Mar-13
$                    23,496.71
$                                            210,010.26
$                                            111,655.93


6
Apr-13
$                    28,335.22
$                                            181,675.04
$                                             83,320.71


7
May-13
$                    28,382.01
$                                            153,293.03
$                                             54,938.70


8
Jun-13
$                    20,208.18
$                                            133,084.85
$                                             34,730.52


9
Jul-13
$                    24,999.57
$                                            108,085.28
$                                            354,328.10


10
Aug-13
$                    36,214.14
$                                             71,871.14
$                                            318,113.96


11
Sep-13
$                    53,338.95
$                                             18,532.19
$                                            264,775.01


12
Oct-13
$                    24,182.41
$                                             (5,650.22)
$                                            240,592.60












11/1/2013 ~ 10/31/2014
07/01/2013 ~ 06/30/2014





$                                            421,460.00
$                                            379,327.67




Actual Monthly Invoice   Amount
Remaing Funding for QY Term
Remaing Funding for OY Term


1
Nov-13
$                    20,754.52
$                                            400,705.48
$                                            219,838.08


2
Dec-13
$                    32,493.45
$                                            368,212.03
$                                            187,344.63


3
Jan-14
$                    35,839.05
$                                            332,372.98
$                                            151,505.58


4
Feb-14
$                    25,152.64
$                                            307,220.34
$                                            126,352.94


5
Mar-14
$                    20,554.94
$                                            286,665.40
$                                            105,798.00


6
Apr-14
$                    26,226.54
$                                            260,438.86
$                                             79,571.46


7
May-14
$                    24,733.44
$                                            235,705.42
$                                             54,838.02


8
Jun-14
$                    21,063.69
$                                            214,641.73
$                                             33,774.33


9
Jul-14
$                    23,700.00
$                                            190,941.73



10
Aug-14
$                    33,210.00
$                                            157,731.73



11
Sep-14





12
Oct-14






For the Pivot Table I would hope it can look like this:



Pivot Table









QY "Year" $Funding Remaining
OY "Year" $Funding Remaining
Request More Funding Status



"Year" or "Month"


"Please Request More"



"Year"


"Safe"












You can add input data using Markdown Tables. Probably you should add your input data and expected output.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thank you for the suggestion. I added the table and would appreciate anyone that can offer some suggestion for the table. I am really stuck....

I've seen you added your input table but I'm not able to understand properly how should be the expected output. What are you looking for exactly? I would like to know say in April how much funding I have used from the November – October (QY Term) funding bucket vs July – June (OY Term) funding bucket. What would be the result if you do it manually?

This would go a long way if we knew exactly what you were trying to do. We see the tables, but we don't know what exactly is the goal of the pivot. Filter the dates after the given date and then sum the difference of the 2 months? Give us an example of how you expect one of these to go, doesn't have to be a pivot table but just so we know what the end result is supposed to look like.

Good evening everyone, thank you for being patient with me. So what I want to do is to create a table like the one I created in the picture to track a specific month after subtracting the invoice amount to figure out how much funding I have left. The difficulty is that my organization functions on a July - June cycle but some of my project functions on a Nov - Oct cycle. For example, in the July '12 - June '13 cycle I have to figure out the total funding first by dividing the total funding for Nov. '12 ~ Oct. '13 by 12 months.  Then use that resulting amount for Nov . '12 - June '13.

@MarkS. I would say a running tally tracker for two different total fund pool/ bucket remaining on two different fiscal terms (Nov - Oct. then July - June).

@QED_Millenium So walk us through the inputs you would put and what you'd want the table to look like in the question. I only saw just saw your comment say that the image is your output? Then what are your inputs? This seems absolutely doable with a combination of a few formulas, but know nothing of what the input->output relationship is here.

@MarkS. I hope I am understanding and answering your question correctly. So my inputs are: 1) The actual invoice amounts per month (I have to put this in) 2) I also have to put QY and OY Project totals in: $295,063 | $421,460 | $196,708.67 | $379,327.67 (QY which covers Nov. Oct. are given to us for the project but the OY  numbers for the next term ie OY 2013 - 2014 are calculated by this =(4/12)($295063)+(8/12)($421460) = $379,327.67. The relationship between the input->output is with more input added (monthly invoice amounts) - from QY and OY Totals we have the remaining funding decrease.

To reiterate the relationship between the input->output is with more input added (monthly invoice amounts) subtracting from QY and OY Totals we have the remaining funding decrease. There was a character limit for comment section ^_^*
